# Amplify servers side signin

Tags: aws-amplify, amplifyjs

Is it possible to sign in using Amplify server side and keep session client-side?

If I use `withSSRContext` and `SSR.Auth.signIn` I loose session and current user when I return to client side.
https://docs.amplify.aws/lib/ssr/q/platform/js/
https://aws.amazon.com/ru/blogs/mobile/ssr-support-for-aws-amplify-javascript-libraries/

May be it's possible to set some cookies or what ever so amplify js lib continue to see the user client side (it would be nice refreshing tokens how it does after the client side sign in)?